# append a list with new element, while setting its name from a variable

Tags: r, list, append, rename

I have an existing list:

```
mylist = list("player1"="Mike", "player2"="John")
```

I want to append a new element, "Sam", with a name attribute like "player17", except that the name is stored in a variable:

```
new_name="player17"
```

So I try without success different syntaxes:

```
c(mylist, new_name="Sam")
with(mylist, assign(new_name, "Sam"))
```

Is there a way to do this in one step (I know I could also change the names of each element afterwards in 2 steps with the function `names`).

**Edit:** in my real data, the elements of my list can be data.frames.

Comment: This `mylist[[new_name]] = "Sam"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks a lot, that works indeed! But i'm thinking, in case this  name already exist in the list, it will replace it and not "append" it! Am I wrong? I want to be sure it appends it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To append a value in a key we can

```
mylist[[key]] = c(mylist[[key]],'Sam')
```

For example,

```
mylist = list("player1"="Mike", "player2"="John")
mylist[["player1"]] = c(mylist[["player1"]],'Sam')

mylist
#$player1
#[1] "Mike" "Sam" 

#$player2
#[1] "John"
```

This will also work if the key isn't already used

```
new_name="player17"
mylist[[new_name]] = c(mylist[[new_name]],'Sam')

#$player1
#[1] "Mike" "Sam" 

#$player2
#[1] "John"

#$player17
#[1] "Sam"
```

---

**EDIT :** As per the update, if there are dataframes in our list we can use `rbind` instead of `c`

```
mylist=list(a = mtcars, b = mtcars*10) 
mylist[["c"]] = rbind(mylist[["c"]], mtcars/10)
```

and this works for the above example as well.

Comment: Thanks I tried it on my real data, since one of my lists have elements that are data.frames, and it behaves strangely (the data frame is not added in the same way as the others)

Comment: @agenis So do you need to add that as a row in the dataframe. What are the columns in it and what would be their corresponding values?

Comment: well instead of adding the new data.frame normally, it transforms it into a (sub)list of its columns. Try it with mtcars... `mylist=list(mtcars, mtcars*10); mylist[[new_name]] = c(mylist[[new_name]], mtcars/10)`

Comment: @agenis For dataframe, instead of `c` we use `rbind`. `mylist=list(a = mtcars, b = mtcars*10)
mylist[["c"]] = rbind(mylist[["c"]], mtcars/10)` and it works for the first example as well. The only difference is it changes itself to data frame.